# When to use Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I've attached the following problem (sorry if you cannot view it).

> [image: Problem]

In example 2, the Lagrange Method is utilized, why is this not the case for example 3? What differs when the constraint is an inequality versus set constraint?

Comment: Lagrange multipliers is only used when you want to maximise $f:\mathbb R^n\to R$ subject to the constraint $g(\mathbf x)=0$ where $g:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$. The theorem doesn't work when the constraint looks like an inequality (although in special cases, you might be able to make modifications to fix this).

Comment: so would you need to find and check those critical points (by EVT), then treat the inequality like an equation and find points using lagrange method?

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you refer to EVT or what you mean by "treat the inequality like an equation".

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of clarity; I mean do I find the critical points that satisfy the inequality constraint ((0,0) in this case), as well as apply Lagrange multipliers method? Do both methods have to done when the constraint is an inequality?

Comment: In Example 3, they're using the results from Example 2, so in a sense they **are** using Lagrange multipliers in Example 3 as well.